# A lot of threads in java process

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

Why does a simple Java GUI application create so many threads?

[image]

Comment: this ain't no simple gui, man.

Comment: @Suraj, that's a task manager that he uses to see how many threads are spawned for his java app.

Comment: @Lirik my comment was supposed to be a pun :)

Answer (score 9):

Java uses threads for a lot of things:

- The application's main thread, of course
- Any threads the application starts (e.g. SwingWorker)
- Swing has a separate Event dispatch thread as well as some other housekeeping threads
- Timers, some of which may get started implicitly
- One or more threads for Garbage collection
- I think there's usually a separate thread prepared to run shutdown hooks
- Other JVM-internal things

Answer (score 4):

A Simple Java Swing GUI has following Threads:

```
Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Suspended)   
Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable] 
Object.wait() line: 485 
AWTAutoShutdown.run() line: 265 
Thread.run() line: 619  

Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Suspended) 
WToolkit.eventLoop() line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable]  
WToolkit.run() line: 295    
Thread.run() line: 619  

Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended)   
Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable] 
EventQueue(Object).wait() line: 485 
EventQueue.getNextEvent() line: 479 
EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int) line: 236   
EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter) line: 184    
EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component) line: 174   
EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional) line: 169  
EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional) line: 161   
EventDispatchThread.run() line: 122 

Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Suspended)
```

Comment: Great. What programm did you use?

Comment: eclipse IDE - Start JFrame programm with debugger

Comment: @zim32, that looks like a thread dump. `Ctrl+Break` on Windows and `kill -QUIT <pid>` on *nix will get you this dump.

Answer (score 1):

If you attach a debugger, you can see the names and guess yourself,

but the threads are probably one or two garbage-collection threads,
a few gui background threads like timers, cleanup etc.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you fire up jconsole (free java app in the jdk) and connect to a running java program, there is a "thread" tab that will let you look at how many threads are, along with a list of threads you can click on for more info.