# Why java creates many threads when a simple application is running?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jvm, profiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A lot of threads in java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290630/a-lot-of-threads-in-java-process)

I saw when a simple application is running locally or using java web start(a simple JFrame instance for example), the JVM creates a process that uses many Threads, around 20 or more (I used "Windows Task Manager" to view the number of created Threads).

Someone knows why java initialize many threads when a simple application is running? and
How much of real memory are used for these threads?

I tried to find some information about it, but I found nothing. Maybe someone can help me to find some reference about why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You closed my question because is duplicate. Thats OK, but is a real question. The question [A lot of threads in java process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290630/a-lot-of-threads-in-java-process) was closed as "not a real question" and I cannot find much sense...

Comment: For that reason, among others, I voted to re-open that question; see also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @luix Please don't feel upset by moderation, it's purely to keep the highest quality of questions/answers. People don't have anything against you or your question, but I hope you understand that there is no value to answering the same question multiple times. The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290630/a-lot-of-threads-in-java-process (by the way, there are votes to reopen it) seems like it should give you all of the information necessary to answer your question.